# Laravel query with multiple where not returning expected result

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a query from a Repository in a Model with 2 where clauses.

This is the data I have in a MySql table:

```
id      name            environment_hash
1       online_debit    abc
2       credit_cart     abc
```

I want to query by name and environment_hash. To do this, I created the method findByHashAndMethod() (see below).

But when I use it in my controller, like this:

```
$online_debit = $this->ecommercePaymentMethodRepository->findByHashAndMethod($hash, 'online_debit')->first();
```

or this:

```
$credit_card = $this->ecommercePaymentMethodRepository->findByHashAndMethod($hash, 'credit_cart')->first();
```

I keep getting both rows and not only the ones filtered. What's wrong with the code?

This is my PaymentMethodRepository.php

```
class EcommercePaymentMethodRepository extends BaseRepository
{


    public function findByHashAndMethod($hash = null, $payment_method)
    {
        $model = $this->model;

        if($hash) 
        {
            $filters = ['environment_hash' => $hash, 'name' => $payment_method];
            $this->model->where($filters);
        }

        else
        {
            $this->model->where('environment_hash',  Auth::user()->environment_hash)
                        ->where('name', $payment_method);
        }


        return $model;
    }

    public function model()
    {
        return EcommercePaymentMethod::class;
    }
}
```

And this is my model EcommercePaymentMethod.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class EcommercePaymentMethod extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = "ecommerce_payment_methods";

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        "name",
        "payment_processor_id",
        "active",
        "environment_hash"
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        "name" => "string"
    ];

    public function payment_processor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\EcommercePaymentProcessor');
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add ->get() when returning

Comment: You're mixing $this->model with $model in your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not entirely sure why `->first()` would ever return more than one result, your Repository method had some few glaring issues that's prone to errors.

```
class EcommercePaymentMethodRepository extends BaseRepository
{

    // 1. Do not put optional parameter BEFORE non-optional
    public function findByHashAndMethod($payment_method, $hash = null)
    {
        // 2. Call ->model() method
        $model = new $this->model();

        // 3. Logic cleanup
        if (is_null($hash)) {
            $hash = Auth::user()->environment_hash;
        }

        return $model->where('environment_hash', $hash)
            ->where('name', $payment_method);
    }

    public function model()
    {
        return EcommercePaymentMethod::class;
    }
}
```